# Version of libjpeg while using other package

Tags: python-3.x, jpeg, package, libjpeg

I would like to visualize weather data, which are under the format .grb2. Therefore I need the library pygrib for python. I've already install grib-api and pygrib, as explained on the installation notes of pygrib (http://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/). I'm using python 3.5 installed with anaconda. I ran

```
brew install grib-api
pip install pygrib
```

However when I try to import pygrib in a python script I always get the same error message :

```
import pygrib

--> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Marguerite/anaconda/lib/python3.5/sitepackages/pygrib.cpyton-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjpeg.9.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Marguerite/anaconda/lib//libgrib_api.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libgrib_api.dylib requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.9.dylib provides version 11.0.0
```

I've tried several times to uninstall/reinstall jpeg libraries, or install libjpeg with macports, nothing seems to do the trick ... Also I can't find the library libjpeg when I run "conda list". It seems it is included into some other library (jpeg of libjpeg-turbo), but again updating those libraries didn't improve results.

I would appreciate really any help or thoughts !
Thanks,

Marguerite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found a solution. Libjpeg is updated with conda update jpeg, but not to the latest version. 
The trick that worked for me is to install a bigger package, which automatically update libjpeg. Just run :

```
conda install -c conda-forge jasper
```

After that it worked fine for me :)